# Core Data NSPredicate "deleted == NO" does not work as expected

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, uimanageddocument

I am using UIManagedDocument with Parent Child context.

In my child context I do the following

### Code 1

```
NSSet *results = [self.event.memberships filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {

    return ([[evaluatedObject deleted] boolValue] == NO);

}]];
```

Above code returns the expected results (only  Not deleted members for the event).

### Code 2

But this code does not. It fetches all records.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"deleted == NO"];
NSSet *results = [self.event.memberships filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

It seems confusing. Both should return same results, but `predicateWithBlock` returns correct results where as `predicateWithFormat` returns all records.

What are the pros and cons of using `predicateWithBlock` instead of `predicateWithFormat`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you have defined an attribute `deleted` for your entity. That conflicts with the `isDeleted` method of `NSManagedObject`, so you should rename that attribute.

The following "experiment" shows that strange things happen if you call your attribute "deleted"  (`c` is a managed object with a custom `deleted` attribute):

```
// Set custom "deleted" property to YES:
c.deleted = @YES;

// Use the property, as your Code 1
NSLog(@"%@", [c deleted]);
// Output: 1

// Use Key-Value Coding, as your Code 2
NSLog(@"%@", [c valueForKey:@"deleted"]);
// Output: 0

// Now really delete the object and try again:
[context deleteObject:c];
NSLog(@"%@", [c valueForKey:@"deleted"]);
// Output: 1
```

Your "Code 1" refers to the property, therefore it returns the expected result. "Code 2" uses Key-Value Coding, and `[c valueForKey:@"deleted"]` returns `YES` if the object
actually has been deleted from the context!

So renaming that attribute should solve your problem. Unfortunately the compiler does not
emit warnings if an attribute name conflicts with a built-in method.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. but isDeleted and deleted are two different name. when i checked NSManagedObject.h header file `// state - methods can be used through KVC, for example for enabling/disabling widgets based on the state of the object
- (BOOL)isInserted;
- (BOOL)isUpdated;
- (BOOL)isDeleted;` may be apple has some private property like

Answer (score 0):

Use the formatting placeholder to replace the bool value:

`NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@",
@"deleted", @(NO)];`

Your use of the key path is probably ok, but the right-hand side probably doesn't look like "NO" to the parser.

Comment: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", @"deleted", @(NO)]` is the same as `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"deleted == NO"]`, there is no difference.