# NSFetchedResultsController updating with wrong update type

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uicollectionview, magicalrecord

**Please see the comments before blindly voting this as a duplicate. It isn't a duplicate question.**

First - I'm using `MagicalRecord` for core data.
Second - My `UICollectionView` is populated with an `NSFetchedResultsController`.

The `NSPredicate` for the `NSFetchedResultsController` is ...

```
NSPredicate *eventPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"event = %@", self.event];
NSPredicate *deletedPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"deleted == NO"];

NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[eventPredicate, deletedPredicate]];
```

When I add new items to CoreData using Magical Record's `saveWithBlock` the `collectionView` updates properly and animates the changes into view.

The problem is that when I change the value of deleted to @YES...

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    Photo *photo = [[self photoAtIndexPath:[self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell]] inContext:localContext];
    photo.deleted = @YES;
}];
```

Then the `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate methods fire except it fires with the change type `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate`. This isn't what it should be though. It should be `NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete` as changing the value of deleted should remove it from the fetch request.

I don't want to just delete the object as I need to update a server with the deleted ID.

Also, if I then pop the view and push it back again the photo is gone so I know it is updating it properly and I know it's removing it from the fetch request.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should not call an attribute "deleted": See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000242/core-data-nspredicate-predicatewithblock-and-predicatewithformat-in-parent-child or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178847/nspredicate-does-not-get-executed-on-first-launch.

Comment: Excellent thanks. That has fixed it. I don't agree with the "Similar question" though. Although it is the same fix it is an entirely different "symptom". There was no way I was going to search for that question.

Comment: You are welcome. - I have given those links because they both demonstrate that "strange things" happen if you call an attribute "deleted". It was not my intention to criticize your search effort! - I am not sure if this is a "duplicate question": It is a different question but the same underlying problem, therefore I voted to close as duplicate.

Comment: After reading [Proper Handling for Different-Question-Same-Answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57836/proper-handling-for-different-question-same-answer) on meta.stackoverflow.com I have now given an answer (I cannot revoke the closing vote :-)

Comment: Thanks very much :) Accepted the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must not call an attribute "deleted", because that conflicts with the `isDeleted` method of `NSManagedObject`.

See  [Core Data NSPredicate "deleted == NO" does not work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000242/core-data-nspredicate-predicatewithblock-and-predicatewithformat-in-parent-child) 
or [NSPredicate does not get executed on first launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178847/nspredicate-does-not-get-executed-on-first-launch)
for different examples that "strange things" happen if an attribute is called "deleted".