# Model valueForKeyPath not working for dates?

Tags: objective-c

I have a model inheriting from NSManagedObject named "Deletion" representing a coredata entity "Deletion", so in Deletion.m I got the following method:

```
- (NSString *)toJSON
{
    NSArray *keys         = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"table", @"recordid", @"deleted", nil];
    NSMutableString *json = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];

    for(int i = 0; i < [keys count]; i++) {
        NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:i];
        id value      = [self valueForKeyPath:key];
        [json appendFormat:@"%@ \"%@\": \"%@\"", (i == 0 ? @"" : @", "), key, value];
        NSLog(@"deletion entry %@ has value %@", key, value);
    }
        NSLog(@"deleted has value %@", self.deleted);

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{ %@ }", json];
}
```

This will print to the output the following:

```
2014-09-17 10:36:18.779 Heater (T)[905:60b] deletion entry table has value Piperun
2014-09-17 10:36:18.780 Heater (T)[905:60b] deletion entry recordid has value 256
2014-09-17 09:42:32.762 Heater (T)[876:60b] deletion entry deleted has value 0
2014-09-17 09:42:32.763 Heater (T)[876:60b] deleted has value 2014-09-17 07:42:29 +0000
```

Why is the direct access to self.deleted working, but now via valueForKeyPath?

[Edit:] I assume it has something to do with saving the model after creating the entry. I'm calling [managedObjectContext save:&error] after creation, nothing else, if that helps.

Comment: In `appendFormat` aren't you missing some `\` before the `"` ?
=> `@"%@ \"%@\": \"%@\""`

Comment: Try switching to `valueForKey:`, as you're retrieving an explicit property by name you don't need to use `valueForKeyPath:`.  `ValueForKeyPath:` is more applicable when you perform complex queries on an object relationship e.g. [someDeletion valueForKeyPath:@"table.id"].

Comment: @Larme Yes thats correct, they got lost during my copy&paste, I added those now.

Comment: @mmccomb Thanks for the hint, I switched over to that one, but it still prints 0 for the deleted field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. Turns out this is a duplicate of [Core Data boolean key value change not reflected in fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107286/core-data-boolean-key-value-change-not-reflected-in-fetch)

The problem being: "Calling a Core Data property "deleted" conflicts with the isDeleted property of NSManagedObject"