# Is it possible to have an NSFetchedResultsController delete an object if one of the object's properties doesn't fulfil it's predicate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an `NSFetchedResultsController`-backed `UICollectionViewController` that is populated by a list of objects. Each object has a BOOL property called deleted. My fetch controller uses the following predicate to filter my objects.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"deleted == NO"];
```

My issue is that when I delete the object by marking it as `deleted = @YES`. The subsequent `didChangeObject:` method tells me that the object was *updated* and **NOT** *deleted*. And the object does not get removed from the collection view. If I quit and reload my app, the object does not show up in the collection view, which is the correct behaviour.

Is there something that I am doing wrong, or is this the expected behaviour of `NSFetchedResultsController`?

**Update as requested here is the code:**

Fetch controller configuration:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"deleted == %@", @NO];
NSSortDescriptor *timestampSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timestamp" ascending:NO];
NSSortDescriptor *prioritySortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"priority" ascending:NO];
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:[GYNotification description] inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setIncludesSubentities:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];       
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                           managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext
                                             sectionNameKeyPath:sectionNameKeyPath
                                                      cacheName:nil];
```

Then the fetch controller delegate methods:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    NSMutableDictionary *change = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            change[@(type)] = newIndexPath;
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            change[@(type)] = indexPath;
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            change[@(type)] = indexPath;
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            change[@(type)] = @[indexPath, newIndexPath];
            break;
    }
    [_objectChanges addObject:change];
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    if ([_objectChanges count] > 0) {
        [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
            for (NSDictionary *change in _objectChanges) {
                [change enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
                    NSFetchedResultsChangeType type = [key unsignedIntegerValue];
                    switch (type)
                    {
                        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                            [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[obj]];
                            break;
                        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                            [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[obj]];
                            break;
                        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                            [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[obj]];
                            break;
                        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
                            [self.collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:obj[0] toIndexPath:obj[1]];
                            break;
                    }
                }];
            }
        } completion:nil];
    }

    [_objectChanges removeAllObjects];
}
```

Comment: That looks like the expected behavior since you're not actually deleting objects, but _update_ property which you created and which NSFetchedResultsController know nothing about. NSFetchedResultsController correctly detects object deletion if you do it with managedObjectContext's deleteObject: method, but how can it know about your "deleted" property?

Comment: Show a bit more code for the FRC config and delegate methods.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSFetchedResultsController updating with wrong update type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283252/nsfetchedresultscontroller-updating-with-wrong-update-type) - Answer: You must not call your attribute "deleted".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That behavior sounds like what I would expect from the `NSFetchedResultsController`.  You are really just making an update to one of your objects.  The fact that it is named `deleted` makes no difference.  In fact, calling it `deleted` is a little dangerous in my opinion as `NSManagedObject` already has an `isDeleted` method.

It sounds like you want to hide certain managed objects from view without really deleting them.  I would suggest renaming that `deleted` property to something like `shouldBeVisible` or `markedForDeletion`.   That way the intent is a little clearer and there won't be as much confusion as to what state your object is really in.

Comment: By calling the property something other than deleted, fixed the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Was having the exact same problem, never even considered that the property name would be what was causing the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete your managed objects like so:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = ... ;
NSManagedObject *managedObjectToDelete = ... ;

[context deleteObject:managedObjectToDelete];
```

Only then will your `NSFetchedResultsController` detect the deletion.

Comment: I would normally delete them, but in this case I need to keep them around.