# Cannot use a predicate that compares dates in Magical Record

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, magicalrecord

I am making a method that will remove all of my NSManagedObjects that were not updated in the last sync.

```
- (void)removeStaleObjects {

        // Delete objects that have not been updated in this sync.
    NSPredicate *stalePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"updated < %@", self.syncStart];
    NSArray *staleObjects = [Node MR_findAllWithPredicate:stalePredicate];

    for (Node *n in staleObjects) {
        [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] deleteObject:n];
    }

}
```

The code keeps failing on the MR_findAll... line with

```
[__NSDate objCType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I have checked my syntax with the apple documentation and I am 99% positive that I am creating the predicate correctly, startDate is just

```
_startDate = [NSDate date];
```

that gets run prior to my sync. then after my sync I call

```
[self removeStaleObjects];
```

Does anyone know where I am messing up?

**Update**: I was able to get it to work by storing the update time as a double. However, I am still interested in getting it to work with NSDates so if anyone figures something out, please post it here.

Comment: As a side note, in MagicalRecord, you can use: [Node deleteAllMatchingPredicate:stalePredeicate] for a one line solution

Comment: Thanks, I missed that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the name "updated" of your attribute. It conflicts with the `isUpdated` method of `NSManagedObject`. (See [Core Data NSPredicate "deleted == NO" does not work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000242/core-data-nspredicate-predicatewithblock-and-predicatewithformat-in-parent-child) for a similar issue with a "deleted" attribute.)

If you rename your attribute, everything works as expected.

Comment: then why does it work if I change updated from Date to Double?

Comment: That might be pure chance. It could even be that the predicate works but returns wrong results. See my answer to above linked question where I showed that "strange things happen" if you call an attribute "deleted". I suppose the same applies here.

Comment: Have a look at the docs, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdManagedObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003397-SW7 If changing your attribute to updatedDate doesn't work, well, something is really hosed.

Comment: @casademora: It is documented that you should not override methods such as `isUpdated` (and Xcode actually warns you if you call an attribute "isUpdated"). But there is no method `updated`, so it is not obvious that an attribute "updated" could cause problems. I assume this is caused by Key-Value accessor patterns (`isFoo` can be the getter method for a Boolean property `foo`). Unfortunately, this is not well documented and Xcode does not emit a warning.

Comment: @Kronusdark: Does it work for you if you rename the attribute?

Comment: Just got around to revisiting that code, and yes, that was the issue. works fine with NSDate now.

Answer (score 1):

It also looks to my that your predicate is formatted correctly. Here are a couple things you can do:

1) When debugging this, print out that predicate. You should see something like:

```
updatedDate < {some integer value}
```

Dates are stored as integers under the covers, and a predicate converts it properly as well. If your predicate isn't printable in the debugger, you'll know right away

2) Check your **updatedDate** type. Make sure that's a date (I trust it's already a date, but you didn't specify in your question)

3) Make sure your **Node** object has the **updatedDate** attribute on it.

Comment: Yea, all my date objects are populating correctly, I can print them out and they are not nil. My predicate looks like this `(lldb) po stalePredicate
$2 = 0x1d564f50 updated < CAST(390414548.526138, "NSDate")`