# Conforming to a protocol on a class extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm working on a Core Data application where my entities have a common property called `deleted` (I'm implementing logical deletion in the app).

While all the entities could inherit from a common one, I would like to avoid it (I don't like how when using inheritance all the entities end up in the same table, but I digress).

In order to keep the code tidy, I implemented a protocol as such:

```
@protocol SPRLogicalDeleteEntity <NSObject>

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * deleted;

@end
```

and I want all the `NSManagedObject` subclasses to conform to this protocol, so the code looks better. In order for the code to be maintainable, I don't want to add the protocol to the generated `NSManagedObject` subclasses, so instead, I created a class extension:

```
@interface Product () < SPRLogicalDeleteEntity >

@end
```

that I use only to *mark* the entity as conforming to my protocol.

The problem I'm having is that calls to `conformsToProtocol:@protocol(SPRLogicalDeleteEntity)` return `NO`.

I haven't tried mogenerator (but I could if strictly required). Any tip? Could this be because the class extension is empty and thus not loading?

Comment: Yes, I am. The thing is that it doesn't have an accompanying implementation block, as it's only a marker.

Comment: Oh, I deleted my comment by mistake. Anyway, if it's a class extension then it has an implementation block. It's the one inside `Product.m`. Just make sure to include the extension header from `Product.m`.

Comment: Side note: Don't call a managed object property "deleted", or strange things may happen (compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/16003894/1187415).

Comment: Perhaps you could try overriding the `conformsToProtocol:` method to return `YES` for this protocol? Or will that tear apart the fabric of spacetime?

Comment: @MartinR thank's for the side note! Probably saved me tons of time in my future!

Comment: @Maarten I would feel dirty as hell :)

Comment: @pgb :] Well, perhaps that's still your best bet considering that `conformsToProtocol:` "determines conformance solely on the basis of the formal declarations in header files" [source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/conformsToProtocol:)

Comment: @Maarten It should still work without problems. Adopting protocols on class extensions is pretty common. I guess it's some header import mixup. Maybe cyclical dependency in headers?

Comment: @Maarten Maybe, but I could not find it. I switched to `mogenerator` that creates a subclass instead, to get back to work, but it's still puzzling me.

Comment: As an aside, using mogenerator is an extremely good idea even if it's not "strictly required". It's a much, much better way to deal with custom subclasses.

Comment: You could add a fake method to the protocol and then check in the class importing the extension, if it sees the method. Just to see what happens there.

Comment: @pgb: What exactly is your goal? Do you want to ensure that all managed object subclasses conform to the protocol at compile time? Or you want to check the conformance at runtime?

Comment: I want to check the conformance at runtime, in case in the future some entity of the project does not support this feature. I switched to `mogenerator` and it's working, but I'll leave the question open in case someone comes up with a good answer.

Comment: @pgb: The only alternative I can think of is to create a class *category* instead of an extension: `@interface Product (MyCategory) <YourProtocol> @end` and `@implementation Product (MyCategory) @dynamic theCommonProperty; @end`. - Then "conformsToProtocol" works, but your subclass solution (using mogenerator) is perhaps more elegant.

Comment: Yes. The weird thing with a category is that I ended up with the property declared twice: in the main `@implementation` block, as it's part of the `NSManagedObject` and in the category. It's `@dynamic` so it wasn't a big deal, but anyway...

Comment: @pgb: You could leave the category implementation block empty and suppress the compiler warning using `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-property-implementation"`.

Comment: @MartinR now we are talking! In any case, I think I'll stick with `mogenerator` for now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where I created a class extension:

```
@interface MyClass() <MyProtocol>

@end
```

And instances of the `MyClass` were returning `NO` for `conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)`

I was able to fix the problem by using a category instead of an extension:

**MyClass+MyProtocol.h**

```
@interface MyClass(MyProtocol) <MyProtocol>

@end
```

**MyClass+MyProtocol.m**

```
#import "MyClass+MyProtocol.h"

@implementation MyClass (MyProtocol)

@end
```

Now instances of my class return `YES` for `conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)`

Note that it was necessary to include `@implementation MyClass (MyProtocol)`. Originally, I tried to just include the  header file, expecting the `<MyProtocol>` declaration to be enough, but `conformsToProtocol:` was still returning `NO` until I added the `@implementation` for the category.