# Filtering NSManagedObjects by boolean attribute using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, core-data, boolean, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

I am trying to filter an array of NSManagedObjects by `deleted = NO` this filtering does not work. The `deleted` field has a default value so nil should not be an issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Core Data NSPredicate predicateWithBlock and predicateWithFormat in Parent Child Context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000242/core-data-nspredicate-predicatewithblock-and-predicatewithformat-in-parent-child)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is to change the field name. There are some secret reserved words used in CoreData that are not apparent. I have had issues with other fields called `address1` and `name` too. This person has also had problems with `readOnly`: http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2007/Nov/msg00412.html

Answer (score 0):

comparing your `BOOL` in an `NSPredicate` this way should work:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"deleted == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool: NO]];
```

Comment: Using a plain old `BOOL` is fine in a predicate, as long as the format string uses `%d`.