# Invalid class returned from KVC - confusing for bool values

Tags: objective-c, core-data

The code is easy to understand, but output is not.

Screen of xcdatamodel editor:

[image: cl.ly/image/3U0P1W301K06]

The type of `deleted` is `String`.

```
@interface Row : NSManagedObject
    (...)
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * deleted;
@end

@implementation Row
    (...)
    @dynamic deleted;
@end
```

Somewhere else in code:

```
Row *row = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSString* fixedTypeDeletedClassString = NSStringFromClass([row.deleted class]);
NSString* KVCDeletedClassString = NSStringFromClass([[row valueForKeyPath:@"deleted"] class]);

NSLog(@"%@ is %@", row.deleted, fixedTypeDeletedClassString);
NSLog(@"%@ is %@", [row valueForKeyPath:@"deleted"], KVCDeletedClassString);
```

The output is:

```
2014-05-07 17:29:26.170 iOSplayground[20814:90b] false is __NSCFString
2014-05-07 17:29:26.171 iOSplayground[20814:90b] 0 is __NSCFNumber
```

Why the class of the property is different?

Class is different, but at least looks like properly casted, but there is a worse case:

```
2014-05-07 17:29:26.172 iOSplayground[20814:90b] true is __NSCFString
2014-05-07 17:29:26.172 iOSplayground[20814:90b] 0 is __NSCFNumber
```

I've been fast prototyping without Row class at first, and used `NSManagedObject` with KVC, and I've lost a lot of time on debuging why there is a property of class that I didn't use.

Answer (score 1):

The question is different, but the underlying problem is the  same as in

[Core Data NSPredicate "deleted == NO" does not work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000242/core-data-nspredicate-predicatewithblock-and-predicatewithformat-in-parent-child)

Calling a Core Data property "deleted" conflicts with the `isDeleted` method
of `NSManagedObject`.

In your case, `row.deleted` seems to fetch the string property,
whereas `[row valueForKeyPath:@"deleted"]` returns YES or NO, depending on whether the
object has been deleted from the managed object context.

Unfortunately, the documentation is pretty vague on what Core Data property names
are allowed, and the Model Inspector does not warn in this case.
Another example is "updated", which conflicts with the `isUpdated` method.