# Xcode 6: attribute error when compiling a NSManagedObject class

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

In my coreData model I have defined an entity `MyEnity` with several attributes. Among them two attibutes :

```
mute : Boolean 
deleted : Boolean
```

I have a NSManagedObject class associated with `MyEntity`. In this class I have :

```
@NSManaged var mute: NSNumber
@NSManaged var deleted: NSNumber // compilation error
```

But the second line produces an error and can't be compiled.
This is the error I get :

> Property 'deleted' with type 'NSNumber' cannot override a property with type 'Bool'

I don't understand what is the issue and why I don't have the same issue for the `mute` attribute ?

Comment: please try to change name.. instead of deleted you change it  to delete 1 and try again.

Comment: Please check in the CoreDataModel what the type of  `deleted` is. Then please recreate the NSManagedObject Subclass via Editor Tab in the Menu

Comment: The problem is the attribute name "deleted". I worked when I changed it. Thanks @Ashok

Comment: @Cherif i think deleted may be the keyword in iOS. so my comment help you?

Comment: I found it by my self... just before reading your comment. It was a matter of seconds. Put it as an answer and I will validate it ;)

Comment: At least the Swift compiler notices the conflict now. In Objective-C, it went unnoticed and caused very strange effects, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000242/core-data-nspredicate-predicatewithblock-and-predicatewithformat-in-parent-child for an example .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSManagedObject has a property named deleted as shown [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSManagedObject/deleted) so using deleted variable name will override that property, in your case with inappropriate type (NSNumber instead of Bool) and thats cause a compile time error