# NSFetchRequest predicate querying correctly, but resulting NSManagedObject showing incorrect fields

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject, nsfetchrequest

I'm have a `Category` entity in Core Data with a Boolean property, `deleted`. As an example, there are 3 saved with `deleted` set to `false`, 1 with `true`.

When I run a simple query:

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Category")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "deleted == %@", NSNumber(booleanLiteral: false))
let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
```

it correctly returns the 3 with `deleted` set to `false`. If I invert the predicate, it correctly returns only the one with `deleted` set to `true`. So far, so good.

However, if instead I run it with `NSPredicate(value: true)` to get all stored `Category` entities, and then print the results, I see a `deleted = 0` property for every result.

Clearly the actual database has 3 entities saved as `false`, one as `true`, since the queries are returning the expected objects. So what might the reason be for the returned results not displaying those fields correctly?

Comment: Please show the code that displays the results as well as a sample of the resulting output.  I suspect you are running into a faulting problem but want to see the code to confirm.

Comment: You should not name a Core Data attribute "deleted", compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000242/core-data-nspredicate-predicatewithblock-and-predicatewithformat-in-parent-child.

Comment: @MartinR That's it, interesting. I marked this as a duplicate of the link you posted, but it might warrant its own answer, so feel free to post it and I'll mark it correct.